# How to make mp3 file that can not be played?

Tags: python, mp3, sox

Is there any reversible way to anonymize the mp3 file so that the content cannot be heard or cannot be played?

Thanks.

Comment: You encrypt it with the algorithm and parameters of your choice.

Comment: Yes. For instance see: https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-password-protect-a-folder-or-file-in-windows-10

Comment: AES encryption should suffice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.